# Preempted lock holder scheduling

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, mutex, scheduling

A thread T1 locks mutex M successfully and then gets preempted.
A thread T2 tries to lock mutex M but it can't yet.
The threads both have the same priority.

How do modern OS thread schedulers handle this: Is T1 *immediately* allowed to resume, or is there no guarantee at all?

Comment: Depends on O/S implementation. While resources held by process X may be freed by OS to be given to some other processes. The OS could also let process X give up these resources voluntarily.

Comment: Also some mutex locks can't be locked if they are already locked. So thread B might have to wait. Hard to answer your question. It is too board.

Comment: in the days before Eunuchs took us down the dark path, OS's typically had generic lock managers that could detect the situation you describe (and even detect and resolve deadlocks).